How to integrate the Phantom wallet in my PHP project?
I developed a mini PHP project that connects my phantom wallet.
The project is running well.
So I used the code in my other PHP project.
But I can't connect my Phantom wallet.
The error is like this:

window.solana is undefined.

How can I fix it?

I think you should switch to next.js (i recommend) or React. There is so many document and videos on internet. Also please don't stuck old tech if you don't need. Btw npm has Solana Wallet Adapter library which is very useful for link a lot of wallet
